# How to mark a custom Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.3 cypher query as read-only

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-5

I am currently working on a Spring Data Neo4j 5.0.3 REST API application that interfaces with a Neo4j 3.3.1 causal cluster consisting of 3 core nodes (1 leader and 2 followers).  For better or for worse, we are also submitting a lot of custom cypher queries to the database using `session.query` a la SQL prepared statements.  When we do this, we notice that virtually none of our custom Cypher submitted via `session.query` gets sent to any of the read-only followers.

I've cracked into the code and noticed that within `Neo4jSession`, the `query` method always creates a transaction with type `READ_WRITE`.  Is there any way to get around this so that our queries get distributed across our cluster correctly?

I have also tried marking the appropriate methods with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` but it doesn't seem to work. When I did into `Neo4jTransactionManager`, I see the following around line 218:

```
private Transaction.Type getTransactionType(TransactionDefinition definition, Neo4jTransactionObject txObject) {
    Transaction.Type type;
    if (definition.isReadOnly() && txObject.isNewSessionHolder()) {
        type = Transaction.Type.READ_ONLY;
    } else if (txObject.transactionData != null) {
        type = txObject.transactionData.type();
    } else {
        type = Transaction.Type.READ_WRITE;
    }
    return type;
}
```

What does that second condition, `isNewSessionHolder`, in the first branch mean? Within the context of a single HTTP API call, we call out to the database at least 2 times, so by the second query, I believe this condition always returns false.

Given these observations, are there any easy ways forward for making my queries be respected as read-only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part regarding Spring: Due to limitations of Spring AOP, it is not possible to have multiple isolated transactions within one class.
The best solution would be to separate the calling code from the transactional methods in different classes. Then the `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` will work.

Second part regarding OGM's `session.query` calls: If your unit of work participates in an existing `READ_WRITE` transaction, e.g. this happens because of the `@Transactional` AOP problem above, there is no way to set the type to `READ_ONLY`. As a default OGM will always create a `READ_WRITE` transaction if no explicit type is set.

tl;dr;

There are two solutions for the problem in general:

1. Extract the `@Transactional` methods into another class and leave the caller code in the existing one.
2. Create the `Session` object manually by injecting the `SessionFactory` and create a transaction with `READ_ONLY` type. (and remove the `@Transactional` annotation)

(as answered in the Neo4j user slack)

Comment: thank you @meistermeier; i verified in our code that we were not affected by the AOP issue. our app fires off 2+ DB calls per HTTP request (the first is an authorization check), which forces the tx manager to flag all subsequent queries after the first one to be READ_WRITE SO we ended up opting to go with the second option you recommended and it seems to achieve what we want.